# How to send and then receive data from firebase in a viewholder

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am making a social media app, I want to add a comment section for each post posted on firebase. Now I'm having difficulties in making the comment section. I've tried the below code but it keeps posting the comments on a single row and then crash the firebase. It is not creating a separate row for a new comment. After 1st comment is added the firebase data base looks like that: [image]

but after I add another comment the "comments" value overrides instead of creating a new child post key.

This is how I'm sending comments to firebase:

```
final String message=myComment.getText().toString();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
    {
        DatabaseComment.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DatabaseComment.child(mPostKey).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("comments").setValue(message);

                hDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        DatabaseComment.child(mPostKey).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("othersName")
                                .setValue(dataSnapshot.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("name").getValue());
                        DatabaseComment.child(mPostKey).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("othersDP")
                                .setValue(dataSnapshot.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("DP").getValue());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

And this is my onStart Method where I'm making recyclerAdapter:

```
mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Profile,ProfileViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Profile, ProfileViewHolder>(

            Profile.class,
            R.layout.commentttt_row,
            ProfileViewHolder.class,
            DatabaseCommenttttt
    ) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final ProfileViewHolder viewHolder, final Profile model, int position) {

            //viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
            viewHolder.setComments(model.getComments());
            viewHolder.setOthersName(model.getOthersName());
            viewHolder.setOthersDP(model.getOthersDP());

        }

    };

    mProfileList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mProfileList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

And this is my RecyclerView class:

```
public static class ProfileViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    View mView;

    LinearLayout mLinearName;
    TextView userName;
    TextView mComment;
    CircleImageView mSetupImageButton;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    TextView post_name;
    private String comments;
    private String othersName;
    private String othersDP;


    public ProfileViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView=itemView;

        userName=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_name);
        mLinearName=(LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.layout_name);
        mComment=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.comment);

    }


    public void setImage(final Context ctx, final String image)
    {
        final ImageView post_image=(ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(post_image, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

                Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        TextView post_phone=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.others_comments);
        post_phone.setText(comments);
    }

    public void setOthersName(String othersName) {
        TextView post_phone=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.others_name);
        post_phone.setText(othersName);
    }

    public void setOthersDP(String othersDP) {
        CircleImageView mSetupImageButton = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.accountImageButton);
        Picasso.with(mView.getContext()).load(othersDP).into(mSetupImageButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do u mean by this line, " it keeps posting the comments on a single row and then crash the firebase". in your code u 1 user can do only 1 comment. others can comment also .. but if u want 1 user to comment multiple time then u need to change some code.

Comment: okay, what changes should i make to make single user comment multiple times?

Comment: is this your question ?? or anything else u have ??

Comment: it will solve the part of my probem.

Comment: what are others ??

Comment: for example if user A has commented "hy" from his account, if i log in from another user account say B and open the same post. then there will be two "hy" one from A and the other from B

Comment: and if i comment any thing from user B lets say "hello" , the "hy " and "hello" will both show overiding each other in the same row

Comment: try my ans given below .. hope this will solve these problems too ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Comment class with comments, otherDP, otherName. now add a new member userId.

```
final String message=myComment.getText().toString();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
{
    DatabaseComment.child(mPostKey).addValueEventListener(new 
          ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           ArryList<Comment> comments= (ArryList<Comment>) 
               dataSnapshot.getValue();
            Comment comment = new Comment();
            comment.setName("Name");
            comment.setOtherDP("OtherDP");
            comment.setComment("Comment");
            comment.setUserID("UserID");
            comments.add(comment);
            DatabaseComment.child(mPostKey).setValue(comments);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

this will create an arrylist of comments inside everypost .. one user can comment multiple time.

Edit: When I use this

```
final String message=myComment.getText().toString();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
    {
        DatabaseComment.child(mPostKey).addValueEventListener(new
              ValueEventListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                      ArrayList<Profile> comments= (ArrayList<Profile>)
                              dataSnapshot.getValue();
                      Profile comment = new Profile();
                      comment.setOthersName("Name");
                      comment.setOthersDP("OtherDP");
                      comment.setComments("Comment");
                      comment.setUid("UserID");
                      comments.add(comment);
                      DatabaseComment.child(mPostKey).setValue(comments);

                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                  }
              });
    }
```

lOGCAT GIVE ME THIS: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.view.IWindowSession.remove(android.view.IWindow)' on a null object reference`

Comment: On which line u getting the error.. Its null pointer.. It don't have problem with databases. 

I didn't write an working code.. It may have some error.. Its ur job to find out.. But the process is same..

Comment: I've solved the error, now the only problem is that one user cannot comment more than once, otherwise it overrides the previous comment, I've tried using push() before setValue() but now i dont know how to get value from firebase because i dont know what id push() is assigning

Comment: This code will solve your problem.. As u are adding a new object to the arraylist and putting the full arraylist in the database.. No way ro replace.. 

Using this code.. Your database structure will change.. Give me a screenshot..